# in Django, how to implement CreateView's function with based-function views?

Tags: python, django

here is **based-class views** code:

```
# views.py
class ObjectCreate(CreateView):
    model = ObjectModel
    fields = "__all__"
```

its simple to create an object and save it use this class.

I wonder how?

what if I want to use based-function views to achieve it?

Comment: The [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/) actually uses function-based views to create an object. Did you do it?

Comment: I did, but the **save** method doesnt work, I want to create a **bookinstance** which it has a foreign key **book**, what I want to achieve is that the **book** can get the name of current book model, not by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a function view you would need to implement everything, including creating a [form for your model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/):

```
def create_object(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ObjectForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ObjectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()  # instance created
            # now redirect user or render a success template
            return redirect(...)

    # if request method is GET or form is invalid return the form
    return render(request, 'path/template_name.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: if form has a foreign key, and it should be given before you save, what you gonna do?

Comment: Instead of ```instance = form.save()``` you do ```instance = form.save(commit=False)``` and then assign the foreign key ```instance.some_field = something``` and then you save ```instance.save()```

Comment: I see, one more question. Should I override **clean** method for every field? like `self.cleaned_data['field_name']`

Comment: No, you just override it when you want to do a custom validation, for example, an EmailField is already validated against a regex, but let's say you want to check that the email is not blacklisted. Then you write a custom clean_email method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn how the `CreateView` works, look at its source code. Or for easier overview of the structure, look at [this site](http://ccbv.co.uk) which lists all the Django CBVs.

You'll find that `CreateView` inherits from 9 other classes, has about 20 attributes (of which `model` and `fields`) and 24 methods that you can override to customise its behaviour.